# Can .htaccess file read "variable" from external file?

Tags: .htaccess

I use a separate file `software_version` that is included using SSI into html files. So visitors can view current software version on download and some other pages.

Also there is an URL to download the most current version of software:

`redirect /download/MySoftwareSetup.exe https://download.somedomain.com/MySoftwareSetup_2018.1.0.0.exe`

I have a script that updates the file `software_version`, and that HTML files display correct version.

But I have to manually edit `.htaccess` file to make redirection to the freshest build work correctly.

Can `.htaccess` read some variable from an external file and substitute it while this file is being processed? Something like the following:

`redirect /download/MySoftwareSetup.exe https://download.somedomain.com/MySoftwareSetup_${file:software_version}.exe`

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @MrWhite it's a shared hosting, and I couldn't get this information. this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166607/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-apache-running-without-access-to-the-command-line just shows me that it's Apache but suddenly without version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Apache 2.4 you can use an Apache Expression in a mod_rewrite `RewriteCond` directive to read the value from the file and use this as part of the redirect target.

For example:

Assuming the file `software_version` is also located in the `/download` subdirectory and contains a string of the form `2018.1.0.0` representing the version string, then in your root `.htaccess` file you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "file('%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/download/software_version') =~ /([\d.]+)/"
RewriteRule ^download/(MySoftwareSetup)\.exe$ https://download.somedomain.com/$1_%1.exe [R,L]
```

The above would externally redirect a request of the form `/download/MySoftwareSetup.exe` to `https://download.somedomain.com/MySoftwareSetup_2018.1.0.0.exe` (using whatever version string is read from the external file).

The `$1` backreference simply holds the "MySoftwareSetup" string from the requested URL to save repetition.

The regex `/([\d.]+)/` captures just the version string from the read file. So, even if there are extraneous characters (such as newlines) then these will not be captured. This is stored in the `%1` backreference and used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string to construct the filename.

---

> I use a separate file `software_version` that is included using SSI into html files.

Although if you are using SSI already then you can presumably modify the HTML anchor in the same way to link directly to the correctly versioned file?